# Unable to understand Abstraction in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, abstract-class, abstraction

I have difficulty understanding the concept of Abstraction. By definition abstraction **is the process of hiding certain details and showing only essential information to the user** from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_abstract.asp).
So below is my class -

```
open class SimpleClass {
    fun engine() {}
}

class ChildSimpleClass : SimpleClass()

abstract class AbstractClass {
    abstract fun engine()
}

class AbstractClassImpl : AbstractClass() {
    override fun engine() {}
}

interface Interface {
    fun engine()
}

class InterfaceImpl : Interface {
    override fun engine() {}
}

fun main(){
    //first case
    val simpleClass: SimpleClass  = ChildSimpleClass()
    simpleClass.engine()

    //second case
    val abstractClassImpl:AbstractClass = AbstractClassImpl()
    abstractClassImpl.engine()

    //third case
    val interfaceImpl: Interface = InterfaceImpl()
    interfaceImpl.engine()
}
```

1.Does the first case qualify to be abstraction ?

2.If yes, then why do we say we achieve abstraction using "interfaces and abstract classes" and why not using normal classes ? from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_abstract.asp) and many other sources which I went through

3.If not, then why does it not qualify to be abstraction as my class only knows about ChildSimpleClass and not about the SimpleClass is this not hiding details about SimpleClass ?

Comment: You might want to google a bit as this is explained in quite a few sites/blogs (maybe not about Kotlin but about java). A good example: https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-abstract-class-and-interface . About the 1st point, Kotlin made the decision to make classes final by default, `open` just says that the class can be inherited. And if you want to add something to the mix, check [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) :D

Comment: This is just a semantic argument about the word abstraction. You’ll get different opinions. My opinion is it doesn’t matter unless you are trying to define a design with someone and you need to agree beforehand on exact meaning of the word so you can describe your design to each other.

Comment: @Augusto I know about open keyword and also about sealed class but what I am more interested in is the first case, whether it qualifies as an abstraction or not.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but could you tell me in does it in your view/knowledge qualify to be abstraction or not?

Comment: You already presented evidence for and against qualifying it as abstraction. It can go either way because it is not a firmly-defined word. It really depends who you're talking to. If I had to guess, I imagine most experienced programmers would answer similar to me that it is ambiguous. Your example Child class doesn't do anything, but if it overrode an `open` but not `abstract` function, it's potentially replacing behavior, or maybe it's just adding additional behavior.

Comment: You might find Joel Spolsky's [Law Of Leaky Abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/) instructive, if only by way of counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have multiple choices to do abstraction with. the first choice must be interface because you can implement multiple interfaces but not more than one class. for example, you can have a class that implements both a `Driver` and an `Eater` interface. but can't do that with classes. and then you can use an instance of your class as either one.

the second choice must be abstract classes. the difference between an abstract class and an interface is state. abstract classes can have state. and if you need state in your abstraction you should consider using abstract classes. for example a `Driver` might not need state, but a `Car` might need it to know if it's started or not(totally depends on your requirements)

the problem with an open class is that you can't **force** subclasses to implement a method. and also you always need to have implementations for your methods.

also, abstraction is not only about hiding details. it's also about setting rules for your class. for example a class `Engine` should always have a name and that changes when the type of engine changes. and a `start()` method that works based on name:

```
abstarct class Engine {

    var isStarted = false

    abstract val name: String

    fun start() {
        isStarted = true
        println("engine $name started")
    }
}
```

so as long as you can't define rules with open classes, you should not consider it an abstraction. but as Tenfour04 said in comments, This is just a semantic argument about the word abstraction. but it's important to know the difference.

Comment: I understood the point you are trying to make however it is not satisfactory to me completely il wait for a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why I do not feel satisfactory is because I can achieve what u said about rules through normal class also eg 

open class SimpleClass {
    open var name:String = "SimpleClass"
    fun engine() {
        println("engine $name started")
    }
}

class ChildSimpleClass : SimpleClass(){
    override var name = "ChildSimpleClass"
}

Comment: no, you can't achieve that with open class, the children of an open class are not forced to override the parent method. but if you use an abstract class or interface, the children are forced to override the method @AkshayShah

Comment: in this example,  the `Engine` class, if you use open class instead of abstract class, a child of Engine, let's say `GoodEngine` can inherit the name of the parent without overriding it, but that's against our rule that every type of engine has a unique name. in simple words open class is for inheritance not abstraction